# Error on running command on Cordova: cordova emulate command

Tags: android, cordova

I have followed all steps in installing required packages in using android platform. All are all set up, Android SDK, Android Studio and Gradle. However, when I run cordova emulate command I got the following messages:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/jcfrane/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.10.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code EACCES
```

I tried running it with **sudo** I got the following message:

```
Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I rechecked my environment its pointing on the right directories. And **android** command is available when I run it.

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks!